# How to fix error "Failed to load Main-Class manifest from ..."

Tags: java, manifest, crawler4j

I download crawler4j on [https://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/downloads/detail?name=crawler4j-3.5.zip&can=2&q=].

I saved in my desktop. After I run crawler4j-3.5.jar, a error is displayed: "Failed to load Main-Class manifest from ..."
How can I fix it?

Comment: Uh you need to put more details or this will get downvoted.  What SDK are you using, and the actual log of the error.

Answer (score 0):

The jar file is not to be ran as provided, since it does not contain a main file (that's what the error says). You should either manually select the main class, or use the jar as a library in your classpath.